# No command Git in Lion

Tags: git, github, osx-mountain-lion

im new in the GitHub world and i need help!!

i installed git 1.8 from [github source](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3&q=&sort=-uploaded&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20Size%20DownloadCount)
but when press git in my console says

```
git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
```

i try modify

> ./bash_profile
>   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/

but not woking, any idea please?

I use Mac OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest Way to Install Git:

1. Install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)
2. In Terminal `sudo port install git`

   - You may need to run `sudo port -v selfupdate` before using this install command.

MacPorts has a wide variety of command-line, X11 or Aqua based open-source software for mac without the need for messing with the source to get things to compile.  You can see a list of all the ports [here](http://www.macports.org/ports.php).

Comment: MacPorts also provides consistency since you can remove packages easily (`sudo port remove git`).  If you compile from source, it's much harder to remove it cleanly, even more so if you don't keep copies of the source you install.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

Unistall git

> usr/local/git

Reinstall git 
[Git Sources](http://git-scm.com/download)

Execute this script

> setup git PATH for non-terminal programs.sh

inside packet